# Symfony2 + SonataAdminBundle: Error on updating User's roles (many-to-many)

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

**Entities:**

*User:*

```
class User implements AdvancedUserInterface, \Serializable
{

    ...

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Role", inversedBy="users")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="users_roles")
     *
     */
    private $roles;

    ...

}
```

*Role:*

```
class Role implements RoleInterface
{

    ...

     /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", mappedBy="roles")
     */
    private $users;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->users = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->getName();
    }

    ...

}
```

**Admin classes:**

*UsersAdmin:*

```
<?php

namespace Lan\ConsoleBundle\Admin;

use Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin\Admin;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\FormMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\DatagridMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\ListMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Show\ShowMapper;

use Knp\Menu\ItemInterface as MenuItemInterface;

class UsersAdmin extends Admin
{
    protected function configureShowField(ShowMapper $showMapper)
    {
        $showMapper
            ->add('id', null, array('label' => 'ID'))
            ->add('username', null, array('label' => 'Name'))
            ->add('password', null, array('label' => 'Password'))
            ->add('email', null, array('label' => 'Mail'))
            ->add('is_active', null, array('label' => 'Active', 'required' => false))
            ->add('roles');
    }

    protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
    {
        $formMapper
            ->with('General')
                ->add('username', null, array('label' => 'Name'))
                ->add('password', null, array('label' => 'Password'))
                ->add('email', null, array('label' => 'Mail'))
            ->add('is_active', 'checkbox', array('label' => 'Active', 'required' => false))
            ->end()
            ->with('Roles')
                ->add('roles', 'sonata_type_model',array('expanded' => true, 'compound' => true, 'multiple' => true))
            ->end();
    }
}
```

*RolesAdmin:*

```
<?php

namespace Lan\ConsoleBundle\Admin;

use Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin\Admin;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\FormMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\DatagridMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\ListMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Show\ShowMapper;

use Knp\Menu\ItemInterface as MenuItemInterface;

class RolesAdmin extends Admin
{
    protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
    {
        $formMapper
            ->add('name', null, array('label' => 'Заголовок'))
            ->add('role', null, array('label' => 'Роль'));
    }
}
```

Screenshot:
http://img577.imageshack.us/img577/3565/jyte.png

After updating User i get this error message:

> FatalErrorException: Error: Call to a member function add() on a
>   non-object in
>   \vendor\sonata-project\doctrine-orm-admin-bundle\Sonata\DoctrineORMAdminBundle\Model\ModelManager.php line 560

I think this error occurs because the object instead of 'Role' value is passed to the function Role-> __toString (). How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try something arround this code:

```
protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
{
    $formMapper
        ->add('name', null, array('label' => 'Заголовок'))
        ->add('Product' , 'entity' , array(
                  'class'    => 'LanConsoleBundle:Role' ,
                  'property' => 'name' ,
                  'expanded' => true ,
                  'multiple' => true , ))
}
```

Comment: Not work. Error: "Expected a Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection object. 500 Internal Server Error - TransformationFailedException" :(

Comment: Maybe I need datatransformer, but i don't how to do that with SonataORMAdmin. http://sonata-project.org/bundles/doctrine-orm-admin/master/doc/reference/form_types_and_transformers.html